# Negative margin in Flutter to stretch carousel

Tags: flutter

I have a view like that

[image]

And I would like the image carousel to be without a horizontal margin like:

[image]

My image carousel is inside 3rd party widget so I need something like a negative margin?

I've tried `transform` on `Container`, but it only translates one side.

```
                      Container(
                    height: 160,
                    transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-20, 0, 0),
                    child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      children: [
                        ...
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086486/does-flutter-support-negative-margin

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you set the width to `double.infinity` and if you want to specify a margin work with the following?

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
```