# Extend Map Widget below the bottom sheet rounded corners - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone,
I am new to flutter and don't know all its features. This might be a dumb question but I can't find a way to do this. I have a simple design with a home screen having a Persistent Bottom Sheet and a Container having Google Maps widget.
[Image of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFem1.png)
Now the Bottom sheet have rounded corners so a little space is left around them. I want that the Above container extends just below the bottom sheet such that these empty spaces are filled.
Note: I don't want to use fixed height e.g. height: 400 etc. As this approach can mess the UI in different devices. Also when the map extends below the bottom sheet the Magnification button of the Map are also hidden.
This is my code for the HomePage,

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const NavBar(),
      appBar: AppBar(
          foregroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white.withAlpha(255),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          shape: const Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 0.5))),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          const Expanded(
            child: MapWidget(),
          ),
          BottomSheet(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => const MainBottomSheet(),
            onClosing: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the code for bottom sheet,

```
class MainBottomSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainBottomSheet({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(Object context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 10,
                spreadRadius: 0,
                offset: Offset(0, 7),
                blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal),
          ]),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            RadioMenuButton(
              value: true,
              groupValue: true,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                if (value == true) {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context as BuildContext,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchBottomSheet(),
                  );
                }
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text('Start Location'),
            ),
            const Divider(),
            RadioMenuButton(
                value: true,
                groupValue: true,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  if (value == true) {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context as BuildContext,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchBottomSheet(),
                    );
                  }
                },
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Text('Destination')),
            const Divider(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: const ButtonStyle(
                  // fixedSize: Size(width, height),
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
                  elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll(3),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Find Route',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using Expanded Widget with the Scaffold's bottomSheet parameter but that extends the map all the way down where the Magnification button and Google tag is hidden. Chat GPT didn't help

Comment: If that's possible, won't the zoom buttons and the Google logo become too close to the bottom sheet?

Comment: We can just add bottom padding to bring them up

Comment: But the buttons are not separated from the maps right? I mean, the Google Maps widget is one unity including the map and all its buttons, so if you add padding, the map will be padded away as well, which leave a blank area like the one currently in the screenshot

Comment: The GoogleMap widget has a separate parameter padding for its UI elements like buttons etc.

Comment: Oh I get it, it makes sense now. Although the solution might be not straightforward since [Flutter does not support negative margin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48086486/13625293). Probably need some height measurement involved here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the help of `Stack` instead of `Column`. Initially, you can let the map widget expand to full screen but after `MainBottomSheet` is rendered, get the size of it and return the height with the help of the callback function and update the position of your map from the bottom. The position is the height of `MainBottomSheet` reduced by its corner border-radius of it. Have a look at this modified `MainBottomSheet` with minimal code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  double mapPositionFromBottom = 0.0;
  double sheetBorderRadius = 20.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          //your map widget
          Positioned(
              bottom: mapPositionFromBottom,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height,
                color: Colors.green,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: sheetBorderRadius+5,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
                ),
              )),
          //Your bottom sheet
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: BottomSheet(
                onClosing: () {},
                builder: (context) => MainBottomSheet(
                      borderRadius: sheetBorderRadius,
                      onSheetHeight: (height) {
                        setState(() {
                          mapPositionFromBottom = height - sheetBorderRadius;
                        });
                      },
                    )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef OnSheetHeight = void Function(double height);

class MainBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final double borderRadius;
  final OnSheetHeight onSheetHeight;
  const MainBottomSheet(
      {super.key, required this.onSheetHeight, required this.borderRadius});

  @override
  State<MainBottomSheet> createState() => _MainBottomSheetState();
}

class _MainBottomSheetState extends State<MainBottomSheet> {
  final containerKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final box = containerKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      widget.onSheetHeight(box.size.height);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: containerKey,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
            topRight: Radius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
          ),
          boxShadow: const [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 10,
                spreadRadius: 0,
                offset: Offset(0, 7),
                blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal),
          ]),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            RadioMenuButton(
              value: true,
              groupValue: true,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                if (value == true) {
                  // showModalBottomSheet(
                  //   context: context as BuildContext,
                  //   builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchBottomSheet(),
                  // );
                }
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text('Start Location'),
            ),
            const Divider(),
            RadioMenuButton(
                value: true,
                groupValue: true,
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  if (value == true) {
                    // showModalBottomSheet(
                    //   context: context as BuildContext,
                    //   builder: (BuildContext context) => SearchBottomSheet(),
                    // );
                  }
                },
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Text('Destination')),
            const Divider(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                style: const ButtonStyle(
                  // fixedSize: Size(width, height),
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.deepOrangeAccent),
                  elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll(3),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Find Route',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```