# CSS fix alignment with Button and image

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in CSS so kindly ignore if this question is too silly. I need your suggestions for fixing an alignment problem. I have a set of buttons along with a glyph icon image. The buttons are equally spaced and aligned (height: 18px) while the image doesn't fit (height: 18px). I tried with padding-top and that doesn't help.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #glyphImage {
width:16px;
height:18px;
}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
     <input type="button" value="p">
 <input type="button" value="c"><input type="button" value="/c">
 <input type="button" value="s"><input type="button" value="/s">
 <input type="button" value="l"> <input type="button" value="u">
 <input type="button" value="t"><input type="button" value="tr">
   <img id="glyphImage" src="si-glyph-image.svg">
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Alignment issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several ways you can go about this.

**Option #1**

Since you're using a table and those are pretty good at vertical alignment, you can make use of the defaults.

In HTML `<td valign="middle"></td>`

**OR** in CSS

```
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

**Option #2**

Use `CSS Flexbox` (this can be done just inside a div you wouldn't need the table) Either use your `td` or a container element of some kind (`div`, `span` etc)

```
td {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

---

In either case, I would give EACH element its own `td` if you're going to stick with the table concept. That will give you a lot more control.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="p"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="c"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="/c"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="s"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="/s"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="l"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="u"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="t"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="tr"></td>
  <td><img id="glyphImage" src="si-glyph-image.svg"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, will give it a try and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to use flex target the image and set vertical-align:middle or bottom as you want to align it

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #glyphImage {
width:16px;
height:18px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
     <input type="button" value="p">
 <input type="button" value="c"><input type="button" value="/c">
 <input type="button" value="s"><input type="button" value="/s">
 <input type="button" value="l"> <input type="button" value="u">
 <input type="button" value="t"><input type="button" value="tr">
   <img id="glyphImage" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514214246283-d427a95c5d2f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=673&q=80">
    </td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works fine in chrome and not in Safari browser.

Comment: You'll need to use vendor prefixes: eg `-webkit-property`

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most elegant solution but you could use negative margin to align the items. So if the `img` tag had a `margin-bottom: -4px` for example the image would line up with the buttons.

Seemingly negative margins get a bad rep but there are some valid points in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840237/why-use-negative-margins/1840247) about why it's okay to use them.